# UITableView images - save two images or resize?

Tags: iphone, image, memory, uitableview

I have UITableView with cells. Cell contains image, label and detail label. Then I've got a DetailView, where I load big size of same image which is in cell. And my question is: It's better to save 2 images (small and big) or resize one? Thx for replays.

Comment: Please add a few more details. Are these images stored locally, or are they "baked" into the application itself (i.e. as a resource), or are they downloaded from a web resource somewhere? What is the size difference (this is important because you can generally only shrink an image down to about 25% of its original size before you get horrific distortion from information loss)?

Comment: Images are transfered from photo library. Images in cells have size 40x40 and large images have "photo size". Maybe It was better to resize both...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I guess you should use two different images.

When dealing with potentially large lists it is usually a good thing to be quite resource-aware. So if you scroll through the list you might easily have to load 100 images. However the detail view very likely to be shown much less often. So only load a big image if the user really intends to see it.

Since your application runs on a iPhone you also have to consider its 'limited resources' and the fact that the user might pay for data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the UITableView load a lot of big images, it will scroll very badly because big images will take more time to be allocated and processed. It'is much better to save two images to do not frustrate the user with a slow application.